# Identify rows of a 2d array as belonging to 1 of 3 groups and count the occurrences in each group

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping, counting

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 1 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [1] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 1 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [2] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 2 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [3] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 2 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [4] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 5 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [5] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 6 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [6] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 7 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [7] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 7 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)     
)
```

I want to count the  occurrences of `countThis_id` values as they relate to predefined groups.

- if `1`, then add one to the `count_1` group total
- if `2`, then add one to the `count_2` group total,
- if any other value, then add one to the `the_Rest` group total.

My desired result:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 1 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [1] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 1 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [2] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 2 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [3] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 2 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [4] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 5 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [5] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 6 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [6] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 7 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)
    [7] => Array ( [countThis_id] => 7 [icon] => add.gif [url] => add.php)   
    [8] => Array ( [count_1] => 2 [count_2] => 2 [the_Rest] => 4)   
)
```

Comment: Do you know that your array code is malformed? The indexes should not have square brackets round them, also, [icon] should be "icon", add.gif should be "add.gif", [url] should be "url", etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array('count_1' => 0, 'count_2'=>0, 'the_Rest'=>0);
foreach($array as $arr){
   if($arr['countThis_id'] == 2){
     $result['count_1']++;
   }
   else if($arr['countThis_id'] == 1){
     $result['count_1']++;
   }
   else {
     $result['the_rest']++;
   }
}

array_push($array, $result);
var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

The three-way comparison operator (aka: "spaceship operator") returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`.  Your task requires identifying data into three distinct groups.  Because you are seemingly evaluating on integers greater than zero and need a group for `1`, `2`, and then any other number, you can compare each encountered number against `2` and leverage a mapping array to eliminate the need for an `if` block.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/WLUM1))

```
$buckets = [-1 => 'count_1', 0 => 'count_2', 1 => 'the_Rest'];
$totals = array_fill_keys($buckets, 0);
foreach ($array as ['countThis_id' => $id]) {
    ++$totals[$buckets[$id <=> 2]];
}
$array[] = $totals;
var_export($array);
```

Or similarly, use `match()`. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/dpGQv)

```
$totals = ['count_1' => 0, 'count_2' => 0, 'the_Rest' => 0];
foreach ($array as ['countThis_id' => $id]) {
    ++$totals[match ($id) {
        1 => 'count_1',
        2 => 'count_2',
        default => 'the_Rest',
    }];
}
$array[] = $totals;
var_export($array);
```